# Courses that fit in my ... study plan/ curriculum?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There is a sentence from my motivational letter:

*As a student of geomatics which is a highly specialized field I have been struggling to find a university that would offer courses **I’d like to take**.*

I want to stress that this university I am applying to offers courses that are very similar to courses that I would be taking at my home university. So instead of:

*courses **I’d like to take***

I want to say something about the courses fitting my study plan. Now my question:

Would a native speaker say *"study plan"*? If not, how would you call it? I thought the right word would be curriculum but I when I google it nobody seems to use it in this way.

Comment: You might refer to *courses that meet your needs/requirements* or *courses that will assist you to achieve your goals*. **Study plan** suggests that you have already decided on courses while **curriculum* implies that you are already committed to a course of study.

Comment: You could say "the courses associated with this field" or "the corresponding coursework" or "a suitable curriculum" or "classes appropriate for this course of study" or "coursework matching this area of interest" or some combination of these.

Answer (score 1):

> courses **I’d like to take**

Although the meaning can be understood, it is not suitable to use "I'd like to take", because you did not mention anything about what courses you would want to take. Maybe cooking or archery are among your interests too.

Of course, you imply "courses related to geomatics". Therefore, you may use something like:

> - courses in the field of geomatics, and the related fields
> - courses which will help me specialize in my area of interest (geomatics)

or even:

> - courses in this field

(since you already mentioned it is geomatics).